# ANSI C: How do you ingest input from user and then print it in reverse?

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm attempting to write a program (for class) that allows a user to type in a string and then outputs that string in reverse and it does this until the user types in "Done", "done", or "d".

Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 50

int main(void) {

   char userText[BUFFER_SIZE];
   int i;
   int len;
   
   do
   {
      fgets(userText, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
      userText[(len = strcspn (userText, "\n"))] = 0;   
         
      for ( i = len - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
      {
         printf("%c", userText[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
      
   } while ( ( strcmp(userText, "Done") != 0 ) && ( strcmp(userText, "done") != 0 ) && ( strcmp(userText, "d") != 0 ) );
   
   return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I used fgets because I have to allow the user to input a string that includes spaces and then I also cleared the buffer to avoid new lines. Here is the question I have to answer:

[image]

And here's my current output:
[image]

Comment: Please read [ask]. You've got an interesting statement of work there, but I don't see any questions.

Comment: You don't change `len` after each call to `fgets`

Comment: Consider making use of a `do-while` loop so you don't have to duplicate the `fgets` stuff both before the loop and during the loop.

Comment: Your loop termination logic is broken.

Comment: Thank you! I edited it to be a question and I've updated the code to a do-while loop as well.

Comment: A `do-while` loop will cause "enod" ("done" reversed) to be printed since printing occurs *before* the `do-while`'s test. My answer solves this by using a mid-test loop: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65929023/14430952

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making things a bit difficult on yourself. Once you have the length, you can simply loop that many times, outputting characters from the end to the beginning and then outputting a newline. Simply enclose that all in a loop to continually take input and ceck for your `'d'`, `"Done"` or `"done"` to break the loop.

(**note:**, you can simply test `len == 1 & *userText == 'd'` to handle the exit on `'d'` case without calling `strcmp()` -- up to you)

Before looking at a solution, you should avoid using *Magic-Numbers* in your code (e.g. `50`).  Instead:

```
...
#define MAXC 50     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main(void) {

    char userText[MAXC];
    ...
        if (!fgets (userText, MAXC, stdin))         /* validate EVERY user-input */
            return 1;
```

That way if you need to change the length of your string, you have a single, convenient location to adjust the length without having to pick though all function calls or loop limits to make the change.

**Validate EVERY Input**

Regardless what input function you are using, you cannot use it correctly unless you are ***checking the return*** to determine if the input succeeded or failed. You are using `fgets()` here (good for you!), but you still need to check the return. `fgets()` will return a pointer to the filled buffer on success, or `NULL` on `EOF` or stream error. So, you simply need to ensure that the return is not `NULL` to validate characters were save in `userText`, e.g.

```
        if (!fgets (userText, MAXC, stdin))         /* validate EVERY user-input */
            return 1;
```

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* on your first iteration with `len-1` in:

```
    int len;
    ...
        userText[len-1] = '\0';
```

On the first iteration, `len` is uninitialized, and any attempt to use the value of a variable with automatic storage duration while its value is indeterminate results in undefined behavior. Specifically:

[C11 Standard - 6.7.9 Initialization(p10)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10) *"If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate."* and [C11 Standard - J.2 Undefined Behavior](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) *"The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.9, 6.8)."*

**fgets() include the `'\n'` in the buffer filled**

When you attempt your `strcmp()` of `"d"`, `"Done"`, and `"done"`, you will never match `"d"`, `"Done"`, and `"done"` because what is actually contained in the buffer is `"d\n"`, `"Done\n"`, and `"done\n"`. A simple, and robust way to remove the `'\n'` is by using `strcspn()`, e.g.

```
        userText[strcspn (userText, "\n")] = 0;             /* trim \n */
```

You can obtain the length of the line without the `'\n'` by simply saving the return of `strcspn()`, e.g.

```
    size_t len = 0;
    ...
        userText[(len = strcspn (userText, "\n"))] = 0;     /* trim \n, save len */
```

Now your `strcmp()` checks will match.

To output the user-input in reverse, simply loop `len` times outputting characters starting from the last to the first. A while loop provides a simple manner of iterating, e.g.

```
        while (len--)                               /* loop len times */
            putchar (userText[len]);                /* output char (end-to-start) */
        putchar ('\n');                             /* tidy up with newline */
```

(**note:** there is no need to `printf ("%c", ...` a single character, that is what `putchar()` or `fputc()` is for. A good compiler will normally make that optimization for you, but it is good to show an understanding of how output is taking place)

Putting it altogether and providing the optional `"user str: "` prompt for user input, and the optional `"reversed: "` prefix for the output (better than leaving your user looking at a blinking cursor wondering if your program has hung), you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 50     /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main(void) {

    char userText[MAXC];
    size_t len = 0;
    
    for (;;) {  /* loop continually */
        fputs ("\nuser str: ", stdout);             /* prompt for input (optional) */
        if (!fgets (userText, MAXC, stdin))         /* validate EVERY user-input */
            return 1;
        
        userText[(len = strcspn (userText, "\n"))] = 0;     /* trim \n, save len */
        
        if ((len == 1 && *userText == 'd') ||       /* check for 'd' alone */
            strcmp(userText, "Done") == 0  ||       /* check for "Done" */
            strcmp(userText, "done") == 0) {        /* check for "done" */
            return 0;
        }
        
        fputs ("reversed: ", stdout);               /* prefix for output (optional) */
        while (len--)                               /* loop len times */
            putchar (userText[len]);                /* output char (end-to-start) */
        putchar ('\n');                             /* tidy up with newline */
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `return 0;` is the default with C99 forward, but since you specify C89 it is necessary)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/outputrev

user str: Hello there
reversed: ereht olleH

user str: Hey
reversed: yeH

user str: done
```

Or:

```
$ ./bin/outputrev

user str: My
reversed: yM

user str: dog
reversed: god

user str: has
reversed: sah

user str: fleas
reversed: saelf

user str: d
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions.

Comment: This was extremely helpful, but I do have a few questions. First, I couldn't use some of the methods you described due to us not learning them in class, that said, I was able to make some changes and get 99% of the solution-based off of what you said.

The only issue I'm getting now is that the program exits AFTER is reverses the exit statement, "Done", "done", or "d". I was able to get rid of all the extra spaces and new lines and the program is no longer infinite.

Because I can't fit all the updated code here, I will update the question above.

Comment: Continued: I didn't update to use putchar or addputs because I'm not allowed to currently use them.

My last question: why does that format work for strscspn? When I looked it up, the format given is:  len = strcspn(str1, str2);

So just wondering on the logic of your format and why it works in this situation? I understand that strscspn itself is determining the length of the str1 minus str2, but why is userText at the beginning is why is the =0 necessary?

Comment: `strcspn (string, reject)` returns the number of character in `string` up to where the first character in `reject` is found. So `strcspn (stirng, "\n")` returns the number of characters up to the `'\n'` character giving you the length of the string not-including `'\n'`. (very handy function) It works like `strpbrk()`, but instead of a count, `strpbrk()` returns a pointer to the location of the first char in `reject`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not null terminating your string in the loop. You've done it correctly before the loop, with `len = strlen(userText);` but you're not doing it in the loop itself. You need to add the null terminator again after you've read from stdin.

A better solution to this problem is to use a mid-test loop rather than a pre-test loop. That way, you can read from stdin in *one* place in the code rather than two, eliminating code duplication.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char userText[50];
    int i;
    int len;

    for (;;) {
        fgets(userText, 50, stdin);
        len = strlen(userText);
        userText[len - 1] = '\0';

        if ((strcmp(userText, "Done") == 0) || (strcmp(userText, "done") == 0) || (strcmp(userText, "d") == 0)) {
            break;
        }

        for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            printf("%c", userText[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to research what for(;;) was, but after I did, changed me loop to be more similar to yours and now my program works!